# NEventStore RavenDB - Obtain Commit Data

Tags: ravendb, cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

I'm working through a basic example of working with NEventStore with RavenDB and I've hit a stumbling block.

I've managed to succesfully commit my events to the RavenDB datasource, but now I need to pull them back out, to replay them (CQRS - ES) pattern.

I can bring back the Collection of EventMesssage objects by usng the NEventStore IStoreEvents Unterface like this :-

```
public IEnumerable<EventMessage> GetEvents(Guid aggregateRootId)
        {
            using (var stream = _store.OpenStream(aggregateRootId, 0))
            {
                return stream.CommittedEvents;
            }

        }
```

In each EventMessage, I can access the Header & the Body Properties. In the body property is the actual event that i have submitted, which i want to pull out and inspect.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is correct.

Should I be using the Raven IDocumentStore class to retrieve the event objects or should this be done via NEventstore Stream.

Answer (score 0):

At basic level what you're doing is correct: it's the same code shown in the [quick-start NEventstore sample code](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/wiki/Quick-Start).
If you work in a more DDD context, probably you should emit events from your Aggregates using the [CommonDomain library](https://github.com/NEventStore/CommonDomain) that is embedded in NEventStore, and retrieve them from [IRepository](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/blob/39117af576256f93f4b61f3bd5786a5dee9a7336/src/NEventStore/CommonDomain/Persistence/IRepository.cs) Interface.

You could find some example in the web.
One of them is a my training project: https://github.com/williamverdolini/CQRS-ES-Todos ([some notes about that](http://williamverdolini.github.io/Cqrs-es-todos.html)). I'm not using RavenDB and I'm still learnig...but could be useful ;-)